# My laptop won't boot after fresh-install

Tags: boot

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 (or any other version of Ubuntu), my laptop never boot

I tried to fix boot with `boot repair` but nothing fix my problem. After having run `boot repair`, I got this [LOG](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7029542/). Please help me.

Comment: ok thanks but not solve my proplem any way.i found my proble and my proble was on the bios i make update my bios and after all work fin e now i have install ubuntu 14.04 and i dont have any proplem.(my laptop model is clevo W76TUN )

Answer (score 1):

**Using an Ubuntu Live CD/USB, open terminal and type:**

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

**You'll see something like this:**

```
Disco /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Unidades = cilindros de 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Identificador do disco: 0x7402e25b
Dispositivo Boot Início Fim Blocos Id Sistema
/dev/sda1   *           1        4649    37343061    7  HPFS ou NTFS
/dev/sda2            4650        5683     8305605   83  Linux`
```

**Mount the linux partition (change /dev/sda2 according to your partition)**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

**Reinstall GRUB 2:**

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

**Reboot your PC**

Comment: ok thanks but not solve my proplem any way.i found my proble and my proble was on the bios i make update my bios and after all work fin e now i have install ubuntu 14.04 and i dont have any proplem.(my laptop model  is clevo W76TUN )